# Heroku not resolves local Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I am using custom dependencies in my project, hosted on Heroku, and when I push my changes via Git, the server throws this log (Maven tries to download from public repositories):

```
... Remote repositories download ...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar //Example of correct file
[INFO] Downloading: file:/tmp/build_2b1a7b0432368beb5dc5ba232fac767a/repo/com/example/functions/17.0/functions-17.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading: file:/tmp/build_2b1a7b0432368beb5dc5ba232fac767a/repo/com/example/routines/17.0/routines-17.0.jar
... More downloads ...
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/routines/17.0/routines-17.0.jar
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/functions/17.0/functions-17.0.jar
... More downloads ...
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar (3 KB at 7.6 KB/sec) //Correct file downloaded
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.755 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-04T09:19:40+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/241M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project example-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project example-project:example-project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.example:functions:jar:17.0, com.example:routines:jar:17.0: in project.local (file:/tmp/build_2b1a7b0432368beb5dc5ba232fac767a/repo) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I followed [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies) and I don't use settings.xml file. My pom.xml is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>example-project</groupId>
<artifactId>example-project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>My example project</name>
<description>Example of Maven Project</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>functions</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>routines</artifactId>
        <version>17.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ... More dependencies ...
</dependencies>
... Plugins ...
</project>
```

How can I upload my custom JARs to Heroku?

Comment: Did you check if the `jar` file has your external dependency before pushing to `heroku`

Comment: I only have local dependency because is part of business logic

Comment: ok. How are you deploying on heroku? via GitHub? If so did u push your external jar to your GitHub repository as mentioned in the guide u followed\?

Comment: No, I use local Git repository

Comment: Did you try copying the files from your standard maven repo to the repo created in your project directory? You should have the structure: ${project.basedir}/repo/com/example/functions and ${project.basedir}/repo/com/example/functions/routines with the jars and poms inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it adding [Maven plugin for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin) and uploading the project with the Maven command.